# How to derive the manifold assumption from linearity of a map?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I've learned about differential geometry, where you assume a manifold and define the directional derivative as a linear map $X:f\mapsto x$ at a point on the manifold from functions $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ to the reals.

I wonder if one can drop the requirement of a manifold and assume a topological space instead, because the existence of a linear map (with additional requirements) may provide enough constraints to imply a manifold automatically.

Can I assume a topological space only and have enough requirements for a linear, continuous map on the space, such that I can do differential geometry?

I imagine the following cases:

- the requirement of the existence of a linear, continuous map implies that the topological space is a manifold. or maybe with some additional requirements?
- the requirement of the existence of a linear, continuous *derivation* (i.e. including Leibnitz rule) implies that the topological space is a manifold. or maybe with some additional requirements?
- either of the first two cases and you can do all of differential geometry with *abstract basis vectors* $\partial/\partial x^i$ and abstract coordinate functions $x^i(M)$, but you cannot strictly show that the topological space is a manifold

Therefore, how can I postulate the existence of some continuous map on a topological space in order to have all tools to do differential geometry without requiring a manifold explicitly?

Comment: On what vector space would you like to define this linear map? Note that the space of derivations of the set $\mathcal{C}^0(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$ is reduced to $\{0\}$, so you really need a set of smooth maps to define directional derivatives as linear derivations of some set of functions.

Comment: @Didier On the set of functions $C^0(M)$ on the manifold with the real numbers as the field. So the "types" like in the directional derivative. Wouldn't this imply a vector space at each point and I have not even introduced the manifold yet? Similarly I can define the Leibnitz rule on continuous functions and not refer to a manifold. I'm actually not talking about "smooth" at this point. I rather want to require the existence of a continuous, linear map (with enough additional condition) such that the topological space must become a manifold.

Comment: The set of linear derivations on $\mathcal{C}^0(M)$ is reduced to $\{0\}$. See [this](https://planetmath.org/derivationsonaringofcontinuousfunctions)

Comment: It follows that smoothness is required to define a suitable notion of a tangent space thanks to linear derivations, since you really need to restrict to smooth enough functions, and not only continuous ones

Comment: I don't necessarily require to admit all continuous functions. It could also be a subspace. Then maybe the extra condition is the existence of a non-trivial derivation. It's actually the core of the questions how to rigorously set up enough conditions on the linear map such that you force the topological space to be manifold without explicitly requiring that.